# Rcpp package creation Symbol not found error

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, r-package

I am trying to create a R package with Rcpp.

The main code I want to export is in C++ but it relies on other C++ and C scripts.

My project looks like this :

```
├── DESCRIPTION
├── NAMESPACE
├── R
│   └── RcppExports.R
├── README.md
├── Read-and-delete-me
├── inst
│   ├── include
│   │   ├── Generate_RQMC.hpp
│   │   ├── Get_seed.hpp
│   │   ├── HilbertCode.hpp
│   │   └── SamplePack
│   │       ├── DB_NX.h
│   │       ├── DB_ShiftNets.h
│   │       ├── DigitalNetsBase2.h
│   │       ├── Measurements.h
│   │       └── RadicalInversesBase2.h
│   └── libsqmc_main.a
├── man
│   └── RSQMC-package.Rd
└── src
    ├── Makevars
    ├── RSQMC.so
    ├── RcppExports.cpp
    ├── RcppExports.o
    ├── SQMC.cpp
    ├── SQMC.o
    └── libqmc
        ├── Generate_RQMC.cpp
        ├── Generate_RQMC.o
        ├── Get_seed.cpp
        ├── Get_seed.o
        ├── HilbertCode.cpp
        ├── HilbertCode.o
        └── SamplePack
            ├── DigitalNetsBase2.C
            ├── Measurements.C
            ├── dn2dpro.C
            ├── dnmeasure.C
            ├── ricapdisc.C
            ├── rimeasure.C
            ├── rivis.C
            └── tparam.C
```

Where *libsqmc.so* is the shared library grouping all the scripts in the folder *R_Functions*.

In the main.cpp file I want to call a function from Generate_RQMC.hpp so I added the following line at the beginning of my script :

```
#include "SQMC_scripts/R_Functions/include/Generate_RQMC.hpp"
```

When I run

```
R CMD build RSQMC
```

I get the following error :

> Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
>     unable to load shared object '/private/var/folders/37/vpwyrl2j2bxdj91kh9fktzk00000gn/T/RtmpybFnDv/Rinst2f1e7114fbd2/RSQMC/libs/RSQMC.so':
>     dlopen(/private/var/folders/37/vpwyrl2j2bxdj91kh9fktzk00000gn/T/RtmpybFnDv/Rinst2f1e7114fbd2/RSQMC/libs/RSQMC.so, 6): Symbol not found: __Z16**MyFunction**iii
>     Referenced from: /private/var/folders/37/vpwyrl2j2bxdj91kh9fktzk00000gn/T/RtmpybFnDv/Rinst2f1e7114fbd2/RSQMC/libs/RSQMC.so
>     Expected in: flat namespace
>    in /private/var/folders/37/vpwyrl2j2bxdj91kh9fktzk00000gn/T/RtmpybFnDv/Rinst2f1e7114fbd2/RSQMC/libs/RSQMC.so
>   Error: loading failed
>   Execution halted
>   ERROR: loading failed
>   * removing ‘/private/var/folders/37/vpwyrl2j2bxdj91kh9fktzk00000gn/T/RtmpybFnDv/Rinst2f1e7114fbd2/RSQMC’

MyFunction is the function I am trying to call in the main file from Generate_RQMC.hpp.

I modified the Makevars by adding -I".../src/SQMC_scripts/include" to PKG_LIBS but it does not change anything.

I am using macOS Sierra 10.12.5, R 3.3.2 and Rcpp 0.12.11.

**Update**

I modified my Makevars which looks like this now :

```
CXX_STD = CXX11

SOURCES=$(wildcard SQMC_scripts/*.cpp SQMC_scripts/*/*.C)

OBJECTS = SQMC.o RcppExports.o $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I".../RSQMC/src/" 

PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)

all: $(SHLIB)

$(OBJECTS): clean

clean:  @rm -f $(OBJECTS)
```

But I still have the same kind of errors (for different classes and functions defined in the SQMC_scripts folder) eg :

> Symbol not found: __ZN19DigitalNetGeneratorC1E4_dgtj

DigitalNetGenerator is a class defined in the C file DigitalNetsBase2.

**Update 2**

I finally managed to make it work thanks to coatless' answer and this [repository](https://github.com/grantbrown/RcppCAF).

Here is my Makevars file if it can be of any help for others :

```
$(info The compilation root directory is: $(ROOT_DIR))                          
$(info The name of the shared library to be created is: $(SHLIB))               

CXX_STD = CXX11
PKG_CPPFLAGS= -Dlibqmc_core_shared_EXPORTS -I../inst -I../inst/include
PKG_LIBS= -L../inst -lsqmc_main -lgsl -lCGAL -lgslcblas
LIBS= -L./ -L../inst

SOURCES_C = ./libqmc/SamplePack/DigitalNetsBase2.C ./libqmc/SamplePack/dn2dpro.C ./libqmc/SamplePack/dnmeasure.C ./libqmc/SamplePack/Measurements.C ./libqmc/SamplePack/ricapdisc.C ./libqmc/SamplePack/rimeasure.C ./libqmc/SamplePack/rivis.C  ./libqmc/SamplePack/tparam.C

SOURCES_CPP= ./libqmc/Generate_RQMC.cpp ./libqmc/Get_seed.cpp ./libqmc/HilbertCode.cpp

OBJECTS = SQMC.o RcppExports.o $(SOURCES_CPP:.cpp=.o) $(SOURCES_C:.c=.o)

#all: $(SHLIB)

all: $(SHLIB) ../inst/libsqmc_main.a

$(SHLIB): $(OBJECTS) ../inst/libsqmc_main.a 

../inst/libsqmc_main.a: $(OBJECTS)
    ar -rvs ../inst/libsqmc_main.a $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: FWIW, I ran into a similar problem (functions defined in .c and referenced from .cpp resulting in "symbol not found"), and solved it by adding `extern "C" { ... }` around the `#include` directives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Package subdirectories are a fun topic covered in [Section 1.1.5: Package subdirectories](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-subdirectories) in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars). Unfortunately, it leaves a bit out. So, this question comes up a bit... In fact, I had a similar variant of it as it related to [Rcpp Attribute use in subfolders](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2015-March/008473.html). (Spoiler: Can't use attributes in `src/` subfolders...)

Unfortunately, the only way to do that with folders within the `src` directory is to modify the `Makevars` file as indicated in the later half of [Section 1.2.1: Using Makevars](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars) in [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Using-Makevars).

So, something along the lines of:

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard subfolder/*.cpp subfolder2/*.cpp)

OBJECTS = toplevelsrcfile.o RcppExports.o $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I.

all: $(SHLIB)

clean:
    @rm -f $(OBJECTS)
```

Should work...

Note, in your case the `toplevelsrcfile.o` should be `SQMC.o`.

Not sure about why `symbols.rds` is in `src/` though...

Comment: Thanks for following up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I modified my makevars file but it does not change the error message (see my updated question).

Comment: I think the include paths of `SQMC` might be inaccurate. But, the above is the appropriate way to go compiling and linking subdirectories. Looks like you also have `.C` files... This means you need `SOURCES_C = $(wildcard subfolder/*.c)` and `OBJECTS = toplevelsrcfile.o RcppExports.o $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)  $(SOURCES_C:.c=.o)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to first drop into the subdirectory of `src/` and compile your included code, probably into a static library (or just a bunch of `.o` files) which you can then reference from your `src/Makevars`.

There are packages doing that but I can't think of a great or canonical reference. I tend to prefer external libraries.

As an alternative, you *could* just drop all C++ files into `src/` and R will take of the build.  You may have to adjust `#include` path in the files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the second option (drop all files into src/) but I get similar errors for other functions (maybe because there is a mix of C and C++ ?). I will try the first option.

Comment: If the code is on GitHub, and I have nothing better to do, I could take a quick look this evening and help you out.  Documenting these use cases better is something I have been thinking about of late, but have nothing formal to show.

Comment: This would be really nice, thank you ! You can find the code [here](https://github.com/NicolasSchreuder/SQMC)

Comment: I looked at it, but it is quite frankly a bit of sprawling mess. `HilbertCode.cpp` has a dependency on a header not included. Your improved `Makevars` does not account for the directory levels, nor the `.C` files.  To be frank, I would scrap this and start over.  From a *much simpler* starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your patience. I am able to group every files from the SQMC_scripts folder into a .so file, can I maybe reference this file from the makevars file ?

Comment: Yes. I was about to do that but then `HilbertCode.cpp` wanted an include path it could not satisfy (unless I missed something).

Comment: Actually I just need Generate_RQMC.cpp to work for my package, HilbertCode can be ignored, I'll try with a .so file.